# Updating only one cell in sql from c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

I have a table in sql with many fields.

I want to update only a field named "ready" whose id is taken from combobox. I used following code :

```
string query = "Update order SET ready='true' Where id=" + int.Parse(idComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()) + "";
```

It gives error saying:

> *column name empty*

What should I do to keep the value of other records same and only change the value of field `ready`?

Comment: Although using "sanitized" ints in your dynamically generated SQL is not a [danger](http://xkcd.com/327/), using parameterized SQL is always a better option, because it avoids repeatedly parsing queries that differ only in ID.

Answer (score 3):

`ORDER` is a reserved word. Use `[ORDER]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER` is a *[`reserved word`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)* on SQL Server. You should use it with square brackets `[]`

> Reserved keywords are part of the grammar of the Transact-SQL language
>   that is used by SQL Server to parse and understand Transact-SQL
>   statements and batches.

```
string query = "Update [order] SET ready='true' Where id=" + int.Parse(idComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()) + "";
```

But more important part, your query is open for an [*SQL Injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. You should always use *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*.

```
string query = "Update [order] SET ready='true' Where id = @id";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(idComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
string query = "Update [order] SET ready='true' Where id=" + int.Parse(idComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()) + "";
```